# Anti-symmetric tensor of second order from a vector

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank

> When given a vector $\overrightarrow V$ = $(x, x+y, x+y+z)$. Find the second order antisymmetric tensor associated with it.

This problem needs to be solved in cartesian coordinate system. The problem I'm facing is that how will I create a tensor of rank 2 with just one vector. To use cross product, i need at least two vectors. I'm have just started studying tensor, and also, if i create a second order tensor, to get the an antisymmetric tensor, I'll just have to subtract the tensor from its transpose and half it. $\frac{W+W^T}{2}$ where  W be the second order tensor. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of creating a tensor from a given vector: the first is by using the tensor product:

$$
T=V\otimes V .
$$

The componentsof this tensor are $T_{ij}=u_iu_j$. It means it is a symmetric tensor, so if you substract it the symmetric part will be zero.

The another way is more subtle. It needs exterior algebra. Roughly speaking, the exterior algebra of a vector space $V$ is got by computing all tensor products ($V$, $V\otimes V$,$\dots$) and then antisymmetrizating them (for example for $u\otimes v$ one obtains $u\otimes v-v\otimes u \equiv u\wedge v$). Since there are $n$ linear-independent vectors, you can't have more than $n$ antisymmetric products $v_1\wedge \dots \wedge v_n$ (in other case there would be two equal vectors and then the product would be zero). If $\{e_i\}$ is a basis of $V$, then

$$
\Lambda^k(V) \equiv \langle \{ e_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{i_k} | i_1,\dots,i_k = 1,\dots, n \}\rangle_{\mathbb R}.
$$
($\Lambda^0(V)=\mathbb K$ and $\Lambda^1(V)=V$ is assumed).

If $V$ is also a metric space, then there exists an isomorphism (called the Hodge star operator) between $\Lambda^k(V)$ and $\Lambda^{n-k}(V)$. For $V=\mathbb R^3$, the Hodge star operator gives an isomorphism between vectors and skew-symmetric tensors of rank 2. In coordinates, this isomorphism reads

$$
T_{ij} = \epsilon_{ijk} v_k.
$$

If you compute the matrix of $T$ yo get

$$
T= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -v_3 & v_2 \\
v_3 & 0 & -v_1 \\
-v_2 & v1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

This matrix is just the matrix associated to $v$ when you want to compute the cross product $v\times w$:

$$
v\times w = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -v_3 & v_2 \\
v_3 & 0 & -v_1 \\
-v_2 & v1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
 w_1 \\
w_2\\
w_3
\end{pmatrix} = \cdots.
$$

In fact:

$$
(v\times w)_i = \epsilon_{ijk}v_jw_k.
$$

Exterior algebra is a powerful thing and it appears in differential geometry for example. If you are interested in these topics you should read about it. Peter Szekeres, Mathematical Physics is (for me) a good reference for start. I hope my answer helps you.

There are aslso related wuestions in this foro.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer by @Dog_69 explained the required theory regarding the Hodge star operator and the Hodge dual in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so I will go ahead and compute the resulting dual antisymmetric second rank tensor for the vector in the question.

For any vector $V \in \mathbb{R}^3$, there exists an isomorphism to an antisymmetric second rank tensor via the Hodge star operator, called its **dual tensor** or **Hodge dual**. In index notation (while employing Einstein summation convention), the dual tensor isomorphism is given as,

$$
  F_{ij} = \epsilon_{ijk}V_k \tag{1}
$$
and its inverse,
$$
  V_{k} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}F_{ij} \tag{2}
$$
Which can be obtained by multiplying both sides of $(1)$ with $\epsilon_{pqr}$ and contracting via $q = i$, $r = j$. Here, $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the totally antisymmetric three-indexed Levi-Civita symbol.

Given a vector $V$ as,

$$
V = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ x + y \\ x + y + z \end{pmatrix}
$$

We compute its Hodge dual tensor as follows,

$$
 F_{ij} = \epsilon_{ijk}V_k
$$
Summing over the $k$-index from $k = 1$ to $k = 3$

$$
\begin{align*}
F_{ij} &= \epsilon_{ij1}V_1 + \epsilon_{ij2}V_2 + \epsilon_{ij3}V_3 \\
F_{ij} &= \epsilon_{ij1}x + \epsilon_{ij2}(x + y) + \epsilon_{ij3}(x + y + z)
\end{align*}
$$

Since $F_{ij}$ is antisymmetric, we have that,
$$
F_{ij} = -F_{ji}
$$
Which implies that all the diagonal elements are $0$, i.e.,
$$
F_{11} = F_{22} = F_{33} = 0
$$
This reduces the number of independent components in the tensor from the usual $9$ to $3$, with only $F_{12}$, $F_{13}$, and $F_{23}$ being independent as the remaining non-zero components can be deduced by employing the antisymmetric nature of the tensor,

$$
F_{21} = -F_{12} \\
F_{31} = -F_{13} \\
F_{32} = -F_{23} 
$$

We now compute those three independent components in our case as follows,

$$
 F_{12} = \epsilon_{121}x + \epsilon_{122}(x + y) + \epsilon_{123}(x + y + z)
$$
Since the Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is totally antisymmetric in all its indices, any repetition of an index will cause it to vanish so the terms containing $\epsilon_{121}$ and $\epsilon_{122}$ disappear, leaving us with,
$$
F_{12} = \epsilon_{123}(x + y + z)
$$
Which by evaluation of $\epsilon_{123}$ is,
$$
F_{12} = x + y + z
$$

Similarly, we can compute $F_{13}$ and $F_{23}$ as,

$$
\begin{align*}
F_{13} &= \epsilon_{131}x + \epsilon_{132}(x + y) + \epsilon_{133}(x + y + z) \\ 
&= \epsilon_{132}(x + y) \\
&= -(x + y)
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
F_{23} &= \epsilon_{231}x + \epsilon_{232}(x + y) + \epsilon_{233}(x + y + z) \\ 
&= \epsilon_{231}x \\ 
&= x
\end{align*}
$$

The corresponding "mirror" terms can now be obtained via the antisymmetric nature of $F_{ij}$ as,

$$
\begin{align*}
F_{21} &= -F_{12} \\
&= -(x + y + z) \\
F_{31} &= -F_{13} \\
&= x + y \\
F_{32} &= -F_{23} \\
&= -x
\end{align*}
$$

These are all the components of the antisymmetric dual tensor of $V$. We can now write out the dual tensor in full using its matrix representation:

$$
F_{ij} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 && x + y + z && -(x + y) \\
-(x + y + z) && 0 && x \\
x + y && -x && 0
\end{pmatrix}_{ij}
$$